# Checking if a Part inside of a PartStack was closed by pressing the close icon on the corresponding tab

Tags: javafx, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4, efxclipse

Platform: Windows 8.1 Pro, E4 with e(fx)clipse

I'm currently working on caching opened Parts to reopen then when reloading the PartStack. This reloading method uses EPartService.hidePart() to close all Parts in the PartStack. Since I also need to remove Parts from the cache, I need to differentiate between reloading and actually closing a tab/Part.

I already tried to add the part to the cache a second time before removing it again by sending an event from the preDestroy() method of the Part. But this is less than ideal.

Is there a special event I can catch when clicking on the close icon or another way I could check for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'reloading' here. `hidePart` destroys the MPart object so you can't save it.

Comment: @greg-449 By "reloading" I mean that I repopulate the PartStack with Parts. I have an "OverviewPart" that basically contains a table which is filled with data from a database. I can open aditional "DetailParts" which allow the user to modify the data. These DetailParts are being cached.  The user can navigate between different datasets with which to fill the overview table. When choosing a dataset from which DetailParts were already opened but not closed, the cached Parts should be opened.

Comment: As I said hidePart destroys the object so you can't cache it. You should save the data in some other object which you can cache.

Comment: Okay, saying that I'm actually caching the Part was a bit of an oversimplification. I'm actually caching keys from which I reopen the Parts.

Comment: You may well have to look at the `StackRenderer` to see if it does anything you can detect. The SWT renderer just calls `hidePart` but I don't know what the JavaFX renderer does. It is possible to specify your own renderer but it may require a lot of work.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. I was really hoping for a workaround to be there. Seems like I'll have to look into writing a custom renderer.

Comment: An alternative might be to use a cache which uses `SoftReference` so that the Java garbage collector can throw things away as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the easiest way to do what I wanted to do was to use tags.
Since I could only access the code for when the Part was closed by the program, I needed to set a tag on the part.

```
if (part.isDirty()) {
    if(!partService.savePart(part, true)) {
        return;
    }
    part.getTags().add(Tag.PART_CLOSED_BY_PROGRAM);
    partService.hidePart(part);
    } else if (part.isCloseable()) {
        part.getTags().add(Tag.PART_CLOSED_BY_PROGRAM);
        partService.hidePart(part);
    }
}
```

Now I can just check in the preDestroy() method if the Part is being closed by the program or by the user.

```
@PreDestroy
protected void preDestroy() {
    if (part.getTags().contains(Tag.PART_CLOSED_BY_PROGRAM)) {
        part.getTags().remove(Tag.PART_CLOSED_BY_PROGRAM);
    } else {
        try {
            //remove "Part" from cache
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        }
    }
}
```